# (Python) Function to find sum of values from specific key in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, sum

The error I received is shown below.

### TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Using the dictionary below, I need to find the sum of all of the quantities combined (1+3+3+1+9=17).

```
shopping_cart = {
    "tax": .08,
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "orange juice",
            "price": 3.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "rice",
            "price": 1.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "beans",
            "price": 0.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "chili sauce",
            "price": 2.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "chocolate",
            "price": 0.75,
            "quantity": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

The best function I could come up with is shown below but I get an error.

```
def total_number_of_items(d):
    return sum(d['items']['quantity'])
```

Comment: _but I get an error_ What error? **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Comment: Nick beat me to it.  Oh, and to cover AMC's remark, just paste in the error message as an output, just like you did with the code.  welcome aboard.

Comment: `sum([d['quantity'] for d in shopping_cart['items']])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def tot(d):    
    print(sum([i['quantity'] for i in d['items']]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `shopping_cart['items']` is a list, you need to use a list comprehension (or similar) to extract the individual quantities to sum:

```
def total_number_of_items(d):
    return sum([item['quantity'] for item in d['items']])

print(total_number_of_items(shopping_cart))
```

Output

```
17
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/XFGVG89218)

Comment: this won't work will throw error `int not callable`

Comment: @ShubhamDevgan it should work.Perhaps you have set a variable `sum`.

Comment: it worked for me.  I had written pretty much exactly the same thing and that worked.  paste in Nick's code, works too.  I think you made a mistake somewhere

Comment: yes sorry it worked , i can't remove downvote unless you edit answer , make some change to  your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I can give you a straight up answer:

```
In [42]: functools.reduce(lambda i, j: i+j["quantity"], shopping_cart["items"], 0)                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[42]: 17
```

Comment: OP has a simple question, with a **simple cause for error**. well-covered by Nick.  You bring in, not necessarily bad, but certainly more complicated, stuff.